# QSettings в WebAssembly

Tags: qt, веб-программирование, wasm

Официальная документация Qt пишет, что QSettings должны работать через IndexedDB в WASM версии, но как этого добиться? В их примерах просто new QSettings("", "") создаётся и всё должно работать.

Я смонтировал IDBFS в /WASM_FS/ (в indexedDB.databases() появилась соответствующая БД), и пытаюсь создать QSettings("settings", QSettings::IniFormat). Создается, но не переживает перезагрузку страницы - изменения не сохраняются. Пробовал и settings.sync() вызывать - результата тоже нет.

Comment: В плюсах нужно использовать setValue, а при завершении приложения - вызывать деструктор QSettings. Полагаю, подобная логика должна быть и в WASM?

Answer (score 1):

Вроде разобрался. В доках Qt, похоже, описывается версия для Qt6.7, которая ещё не вышла. Там появляется специальная опция для QSettings.

А сейчас работает следующим образом:

1. В --pre-js нужно смонтировать файловую систему IDBFS

> ```
> if (!FS.analyzePath('home/wasm_user').exists)
>  FS.mkdir('/home/wasm_user');
>
> FS.mount(IDBFS, {}, '/home/wasm_user');
> ```

2. В C++ коде нужно создать QSettings("/home/wasm_user/file_name.ini", QSettings::NativeFormat); // Обязательно полный путь.
3. Дальше работать, как с обычным QSettings, никакой асинхронности не заметил.